# Problem using vertex

Tags: vertices

I was watching a YouTube tutorial and trying to replicate the model but I have some problem. I need to move the vertex but it doesn't work! I can't move the vertex and the model create a new face (see the picture), I think there is some command active but I don't understand what can it be.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no new faces created. In fact, the face has been created before by accidentally pressing <kbd>E</kbd>, and you just reveal it by moving one point from it.

In this case is useful to do:

1. Select all points by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>M</kbd> ⇾ By distance.

It will remove all points that's close to each other and as result remove this zero-area face